# Solve Laplacian equation with Green's function in 1D

Tags: calculus, harmonic-functions, laplacian, greens-function, poissons-equation

I have a 1D Laplacian equation $\nabla^2 u(x) = 0$ with some boundary condition $u|_{\partial \Omega} = g$, where the domain $\Omega = [0,L]$ and the boundary condition is Dirichlet, that for some $x$, we set $u(x) = g(x)$. Now I would like to explore using Green's function to get a closed-form solution. We have two Dirichlet boundaries at the domain boundary $u(0) = u(L) = 0$ and the Green's function in 1D is:
$$
G(x,y) = \begin{cases}
         y(1-x/L) & x > y\\
         x(1-y/L) & x \leq y
         \end{cases}
$$

For Poisson equations, we have:
$$u(x) = \int_0^L G(x,y)f(y)dy$$
but I'm not sure how can we do the same thing for the Laplacian equation while still keeping the boundary condition $g$. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Comment: In 1-d, the equation is just $u''(x) = 0$ which has the general solution $u(x) = ax+b$. Use the Dirichlet boundary condition to find what $a$ and $b$ are.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your comment! The reason that I'm doing this is because I want to figure out how to use Green's function in 1D, 2D and 3D. Therefore I would like to see if it is possible to formulate Green's function to solve the 1D Laplacian case. Do you have any ideas in this case?